have an object rotate back to zero over time
In a Coroutine I'm setting the velocity of a rigid body to follow the touch screen location:
rb.velocity = direction * touchDragPhysicsSpeed;

But I also want its rotation to trend back toward zero degrees. How can I do that?
AI keeps telling me to do something like this:
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(rb.rotation, targetRotation, rotationCorrectionSpeed));

But that MoveRotation line gives the error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Is this the right approach? If so, how can I fix the error? Or is there a better way?

In general .. no need for going through Euler for this ... The rotation you are looking for is Quaternion.identity ...

Sounds like your rb is actually a Rigidbody2D in which case indeed rb.rotation is a float (the single Z-axis rotation - the only one that matters for 2D)!
you rather want
rb.MoveRotation(Mathf.Lerp(rb.rotation, 0, rotationCorrectionSpeed));


As you want to rotate towards the closest multiple of 360
var target = Mathf.Round(rb.rotation / 360f) * 360;
rb.MoveRotation(Mathf.Lerp(rb.rotation, target, rotationCorrectionSpeed));

This should rotate the shortest way to the closest multiple of 360.

General hint: Instead of blindly trusting AI rather consult the API ;)

Thanks for the links. This works for the most part, but when an object has spun around several times, rotating it results in very fast spinning back to 0. What I really what is to rotate it to the nearest 360 degrees (I think). It should rotate back to "true north" from whichever rotation it's currently at, in whichever direction requires the fewest amount of rotation.

@soleil in that case you could simply check to where it is closer and rotate to the closest multiple of 360 - added to the answer

Nice, I had figured out a 360 multiple formula but yours is more succinct.

From the Unity - Scripting API documentation for Quaternion.Euler, you can't pass Vector3.zero as an argument because floats are expected for rotation angles along the 3 axes. You passed a Quaternion, which in this case is Vector3.zero.
Pass the values separately instead of Vector3.zero.
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);


You probably didn't scroll down to the overload taking a Vector3 as argument ^^

Oh, my bad. Rather than taking it down, I'll keep it as a generic reminder that skimming isn't good and by walking an extra mile, you'll more likely find answers. :)
